# How do I get CatAPI to work in simple Android App

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin

I am trying to get [CatAPI](https://thecatapi.com/) to work. My code is compiling and running, and the Dog API (which I successfully implemented) works just fine. However, I get this error whenever I use the button for the CatAPI:

```
I/catError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I suppose it has something to do with the way I tried to read the JSON. However, I have no idea what to do here.
Here is my code:

**CatService.kt:**

```
interface CatService{
    @GET("images/search")
    fun randomCat(): Call<Cat>

}
```

**Cat.kt**

```
class Cat (
    var id: String,
    var url: String,
    var breeds: List<Any>,
    var width: Int,
    var height: Int
)
```

*MainActivity.kt:*

```
private fun catFunction(){
    val retrofitCat = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val catService: CatService = retrofitCat.create(CatService::class.java)
    val callCat = catService.randomCat().enqueue(object:Callback<Cat>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cat>, response: Response<Cat>) {
            val randomCat = response.body()!!

            Log.i("catMessage", randomCat.url)

            Picasso.get()
                .load(randomCat.url)
                .into(imgView)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Cat>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("catError", t.toString())
        }})
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Its telling you the problem... cat api is returning a `JSONArray` i.e. `[{}, {}]` and dog is returning a single object `{}`

Comment: Thank you, @DavidKroukamp .However, I don't know how to solve this? This might be silly, but I am still a beginner. I don't really know what to do here.
I am searching more about it, though. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer @Isadora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Futhering my comments you would want to return a list of cats i.e. `List<Cat>` as its a `JSONArray`.

**CatService.kt:**

```
interface CatService{
    @GET("images/search")
    fun randomCat(): Call<List<Cat>>

}
```

your actual `enqueue`:

```
val callCat = catService.randomCat().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Cat>> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Cat>>, response: Response<List<Cat>>) {
        val randomCat = response.body()!!

        Log.i("catMessage", randomCat[0].url)

        Picasso.get()
            .load(randomCat[0].url) // get the first result as the API states
            .into(imgView)
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Cat>>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.i("catError", t.toString())
    }
})
```

Notice all the changes from `Call<Cat>` to `Call<List<Cat>>` and `Response<Cat>` to `Response<List<Cat>>`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!
I didn't know how to handle Lists on Android, so this really clarifies things. Thanks again!